# .NET upgrade assistant error when converting .csproj file to SDK style for WPF project (.NET framework 4.8 -> .NET 6.0)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

I was trying to update a WPF project from .NET 4.8 to .NET 6.0 using the .NET Upgrade Assistant. When I tried to do side by side upgrade for the WPF project, this error occurs when upgrade assistant tries to convert the `.csproj` file to SDK style:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\nikhilsh\AppData\Local\Temp\UpgradeAssistant\Projects\a24f30fa-182a-40e9-8301-2fe09a378e8d\2024-02-01--18-08-13\Service References\DataDwonloadAuthServiceReference\WBid.WBidClient.Main.DataDwonloadAuthServiceReference.AuthServiceResponseModel.datasource'.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
> at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Services.FileSystemExtensions.DirectoryCopy(IFileSystem fileSystem, String sourceDirectory, String targetDirectory, ISet`1 excludeFolders, Boolean recursive) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\engine\Services\FileSystem\FileSystemExtensions.cs:line 23   at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Services.FileSystemExtensions.DirectoryCopy(IFileSystem fileSystem, String sourceDirectory, String targetDirectory, ISet`1 excludeFolders, Boolean recursive) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\engine\Services\FileSystem\FileSystemExtensions.cs:line 31
> at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Services.FileSystemExtensions.DirectoryCopy(IFileSystem fileSystem, String sourceDirectory, String targetDirectory, ISet`1 excludeFolders, Boolean recursive) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\engine\Services\FileSystem\FileSystemExtensions.cs:line 31
> at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Transformers.ProjectSdkStyleTransformer.d__2.MoveNext() in D:\a_work\1\s\src\engine\Transformers\Project\ProjectSdkStyleTransformer.cs:line 65
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Operations.Operation.d__23.MoveNext() in D:\a_work\1\s\src\engine\Operations\Operation.cs:line 386
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Operations.Operation.d__21.MoveNext() in D:\a_work\1\s\src\engine\Operations\Operation.cs:line 274

Comment: That upgrade assistant isn't perfect. Just do the update by hand.

Comment: As PMF said, it is not recommended to rely too much on the upgrade assistant. You can try to manually upgrade from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6.0, WCF may be one of your problems. While there is limited WCF client support in core, there is no server support. You should migrate to other technologies. Microsoft recommends using gRpc.